# Read a kml file on c# project to give back the information

Tags: c#, .net, kml

I'm trying to read a KML file in a C #. I need to read this information to get the information and treat it. Is there a library to read a KML giving back the information in a data structure? If not, how do you read a KML file? Is it like reading a XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was the new xsd file have multiple namespace, so to convert to classes using XSD.exe I needed two more files: `atom-author-link.xsd` and `xal.xsd`

After that I've used XSD.exe with this command line: `xsd.exe /c ogckml22.xsd atom-author-link.xsd xal.xsd`

Finally, I had classes from xsd file.

Additional information:

I've just found this library (http://sharpkml.codeplex.com/) to read/write kml 2.2 files. It's an update of libkml

Answer (score 3):

Here is my way to parsing a KML file to get coordinates of object:

```
string elementToFind = "example";
System.IO.Stream kmlFile = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("objects.kml");
Xml.Linq.XDocument xDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(kmlFile);
string xNs = "{" + xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace.ToString() + "}";

var coordsStr = 
(from f in xDoc.Descendants(xNs + "Placemark")
where elementToFind.Contains(f.Parent.Element(xNs + "name").Value + f.Element(xNs + "name").Value)
select f.Element(xNs + "LineString").Element(xNs + "coordinates")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Parse it like a regular XML file a search for data you need. I hope this helped you a little.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides an XSD files with the schema for the KML files, you can find it at the location below.

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd

Here is the documentation for the KML format:

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html

You could use the Microsoft XSD tool to generate a class from the schema:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: But, I need a kml 2.2. I try to use XSD tool to convert xsd in classes but I have had this error:
Schema validation warning: No se ha declarado el elemento 'http://www.w3.org/200
5/Atom:author'. Line 311, position 12.
Schema validation warning: No se ha declarado el elemento 'http://www.w3.org/200
5/Atom:link'. Line 312, position 12.
Schema validation warning: No se ha declarado el elemento 'urn:oasis:names:tc:ci
q:xsdschema:xAL:2.0:AddressDetails'. Line 314, position 12.
Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produceincorrect results.

Comment: I updated the link to the XSD file, but it does not validate with XSD.exe.  I've not tried this, but there is a library http://code.google.com/p/kml-library/